# Error with "sudo apt-get upgrade" (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

You can see below the error I encounter.

I did search on Google if the question has already been asked (and answered) but nothing works for me. I can't do `sudo apt-get` upgrade or `install`.

Thanks in advance if someone can help me with this situation.

Regards,

David

```
david@09:25:47 ~$sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up dictionaries-common (1.20.5) ...
update-default-wordlist: Question empty but elements installed for class "wordlist"
  dictionaries-common/default-wordlist: return code: "0", value: ""
  Choices: , Manual symlink setting
  shared/packages-wordlist: return code: "10" owners/error: "shared/packages-wordlist doesn't exist"
  Installed elements: american (American English), british (British English)

  Please see "/usr/share/doc/dictionaries-common/README.problems", section
  "Debconf database corruption" for recovery info.

update-default-wordlist: Selected wordlist "" 
does not correspond to any installed package in the system
and no alternative wordlist could be selected.
dpkg: error processing package dictionaries-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aspell:
 aspell depends on dictionaries-common (>> 0.40); however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package aspell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hyphen-en-us:
 hyphen-en-us depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) | openoffice.org-updatedicts; however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
  Package openoffice.org-updatedicts is not installed.
  Package dictionaries-common which provides openoffice.org-updatedicts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package hyphen-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of myspell-en-gb:
 myspell-en-gb depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) | openoffice.org-updatedicts; however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
  Package openoffice.org-updatedicts is not installed.
  Package dictionaries-common which provides openoffice.org-updatedicts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package myspell-en-gb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of myspell-en-za:
 myspell-en-za depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) | openoffice.org-updatedicts; however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
  Package openoffice.org-updatedicts is not installed.
  Package dictionaries-common which provides openoffice.org-updatedicts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package myspell-en-za (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mythes-en-us:
 mythes-en-us depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) | openoffice.org-updatedicts; however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
  Package openoffice.org-updatedicts is not installed.
  Package dictionaries-common which provides openoffice.org-updatedicts is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already


dpkg: error processing package mythes-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 dictionaries-common
 aspell
 hyphen-en-us
 myspell-en-gb
 myspell-en-za
 mythes-en-us
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you read `/usr/share/doc/dictionaries-common/README.problems` as suggested? Did you try anything from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to look at the `/usr/share/doc/dictionaries-common/README.problems` file as suggested by @Dubu.

1) running   `/usr/share/debconf/fix_db.pl` as root

Look which templates were affected

2) `diff -u /var/cache/debconf/config.dat{-old,}    | grep ^[+-]Name`

3) `diff -u /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat{-old,} | grep ^[+-]Name`

4) `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dictionaries-common` 
(This prints that the package is not installed or corrupted.)

5) `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Thanks again ;)